# How is it possible to align a table to the center in CSS HTML5?

Tags: css, html, html-table, css-tables

Let's say I have a table. How is it possible in HTML5 to align it to the center of the page (horizontally) in CSS? This way doesn't work:

```
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align: center;
} 
</style>
```

I guess `align` in HTML5 works only for divs, but what about tables?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables/

Comment: @Leon - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your css should be like this :

```
.tableclass{
        display:table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```